# Create transaction and so on

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli, fee-estimation

Please explain to me what should be the procedure for working with a **bitcoin-cli** / **RPC** wallet.

For example:

1. Create a wallet
2. Get a new address
3. Sending BTC: creating a transaction, signing a transaction, sending a transaction or some else?

**Creating a wallet

--------------------**
Everything is more or less clear here, we use:

```
curl --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": "curltest", "method": "createwallet", "params": {"wallet_name":"WalletName", "avoid_reuse":true , "descriptors":true, "load_on_startup":true}}' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
```

or

```
bitcoin-cli -named createwallet wallet_name=descriptors avoid_reuse=true descriptors=true load_on_startup=true
```

**Getting a new address

------------------------**
Here we use **getnewaddress**, and the questions begin: if we use **deriveaddresses**, then we get several addresses. What do these addresses refer to, how many of them can I receive?

From the documentation:

```
Arguments:
1. descriptor (string, required) The descriptor.
2. range (numeric or array, optional) If a ranged descriptor is used, this specifies the end or the range (in [begin,end] notation) to derive.
```

What is **end** equal to? How can I find out?

**Sending BTC

--------------**
There are several ways:

- **send**
- **sendtoaddress**

I received the transaction Id, what should I do after that? Use **createrawtransaction**, then **signrawtransactionwithwallet**, and then **sendrawtransaction**? Or something else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Creating a new wallet**

> $ bitcoin-cli createwallet "my-wallet"

**2. Get new Address**

Generate a new address from the wallet which you can share and use to receive coins

> bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet="my-wallet" getnewaddress

**3. Sending Money**

(*After loading money to the wallet*) Send money from my-wallet to bitcoin address "tb1qw508d6qejxtdg4y5r3zarvary0c5xw7kxpjzsx"

> bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet="my-wallet" sendtoaddress "tb1qw508d6qejxtdg4y5r3zarvary0c5xw7kxpjzsx" 0.01

More information on using and managing the wallet can be found on https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/managing-wallets.md

Comment: Thanks, @brandon-odiwuor. 


`>> Generate a new address from the wallet which you can share and use to receive coins`

But what about anothers addresses whic I get from deriveaddresses?


`>> (After loading money to the wallet) Send money from my-wallet to bitcoin address "tb1qw508d6qejxtdg4y5r3zarvary0c5xw7kxpjzsx"`

What is this address? Why I can't use another?


`>> More information on using and managing the wallet can be found on https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/managing-wallets.md`

Thanks. But there is so

Comment: The getnewaddress RPC is generally used to get a new address while the deriveaddress RPC is used more specifically to derive addresses corresponding to an output descriptor

Comment: > bitcoin-cli deriveaddresses "descriptor" ( range )

Comment: `>> The getnewaddress RPC is generally used to get a new address while the deriveaddress RPC is used more specifically to derive addresses corresponding to an output descriptor`  
  
What it's mean? Should I use it? Or not?

Comment: You should use the getnewaddress RPC to generate a new address to use from the wallet

Comment: Thanks, @brandon-odiwuor.  

`>> bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet="my-wallet" sendtoaddress "tb1qw508d6qejxtdg4y5r3zarvary0c5xw7kxpjzsx" 0.01`  

And what about tx fee in this case?